# Scientific large number display after jquery generation

Tags: jquery, excel, xls

I am using tableExport plugin, when I export my table to xls one of my columns contains large numbers f.e `760000322300000939115730`, after export it appears as `7,60E+23`, the console.log shows
`<td>760000322300000939115730</td>`. I have no idea why it happens so. Manually cell formatting (for number formatting ) shows 760000322300000000000000 , for text formatting 7,6E+23

Line responsible for the generation

```
excel += "<td>" + parseString($(this))+ "</td>";
```

https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin/blob/master/tableExport.js

I got no ideas why this happens. Any tips?

Comment: JS can't handle numbers that big in full precision. As long as you just have it as string, you should be fine, but you'll lose precision, when converting to a number.

Comment: @Sirko So what can I do? My draw table from json with this big numbers work all other drawers work too, just the excel thing doesn't work ;\ [ it is string by default so why does it goes scientific in excel ? ]

Comment: The only solution, I can think of, is to somehow convince your exporter to treat those numbers as strings.

Comment: @Sirko using the same tableExport.js handles this numbers ( json, .doc .txt ) - all of this formats displays it correctly why?

Comment: Interesting - I expected at least JSON to fail.

Comment: @Sirko that's the thing. It has to be something with the self excel file generation. Have u looked at the excel generation part? It does it from table, maybe there can I assign a =TextField or something to determine what kind of field it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64185/discussion-between-sirko-and-user3793639).

Answer (score 0):

```
excel += '<td>="'+parseString($(this))+'"</td>';
```

Forces it to display as string

Comment: Pointing out in the text of your answer that you changed the `"` to `'` and added `"` characters to force Excel to treat the value as a string would be helpful.

Comment: @JasonAller Well this works for me that's all I need:p